# Trouble scraping items from two different depth using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've created a script in python in combination with selenium to get the `number` of answers from it's landing page and the `name` of the asker from it's inner page. I know It's easier to scrape the two items by using the question links and next page links but that is not I intend to do here. The bottom line is I'm trying to traverse different places only using clicks. However, when I run the script, it throws the following error pointing at this line `answer = WebDriverWait(item,10)` in it's second iteration.

`selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

***Although the elements I look for are available in both the landing page and the inner page, It's a requirement that I scrape the two items from two different depth.***

I know how to scrape them using requests, so I'm not willing to go that route either.

Script I'm trying with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'

def get_content(link):
    driver.get(link)
    while True:
        for count,item in enumerate(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".question-summary")))):
            #error thrown in the following line in it's second iteration
            answer = WebDriverWait(item,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[class$='answered'] > strong"))).text

            elem = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".summary a.question-hyperlink")[count]
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",elem)
            name = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1[itemprop='name'] > a"))).text
            print(answer,name)
            driver.back()

        try:
            next_page = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a[rel='next']")))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",next_page)
        except Exception:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
        get_content(link)
```

> How can I scrape the two items from two different depth?

PS If I kick out this line `answer = WebDriverWait(item,10)----`, the script runs like a charm traversing different depth and multiple pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal that you get `StaleElementReferenceException` because you leave the page and reference to the `.question-summary` elements are lost.

Error description: `Thrown when a reference to an element is now "stale".`

To do it as you want code below will do job. I changed `[class$='answered'] > strong` selector to `[class*='answered'] > strong`, otherwise you will get an error if question has already accepted answer. If you want only not accepted ones modify script as needed.

```
def get_content(link):
    driver.get(link)
    while True:
        count = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".question-summary"))))
        for ix in range(count):
            question = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".question-summary")[ix]
            answers_count = question.find_element_by_css_selector("[class*='answered'] > strong").text

            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", question.find_element_by_css_selector("a.question-hyperlink"))
            name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1[itemprop='name'] > a"))).text
            print(answers_count, name)
            driver.back()
        try:
            next_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[rel='next']")))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page)
        except Exception:
            break
```